# Why does an array get converted to an object when passing it as props?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, react-props

I'm trying to map each array item to it's own div (to create a TicTacToe board). However, when I pass it in from props, it is recognized as an object. Here is an example:

Here is my App.js file:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    gameBoard: Array(9),
  }

  render() {

    console.log(this.state.gameBoard)
    console.log(Array.isArray(this.state.gameBoard))

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Board squares={this.state.gameBoard}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is my Board.js Component file:

```
function Board(squares) {

    console.log(squares)
    console.log(Array.isArray(squares))

    return (
        null
    )

}

export default Board
```

The console logs in App.js work as expected yielding:

> //(an array)
>   " (9) [empty × 9] "    
> "true"

However, the console logs in Board.js yield:

> //(an object)
>   "{squares: Array(9)}"  
> "false"

I'm curious as to why this happens.
Also, if there is a way, how can I get my component to recognize props as an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `squares` parameter in the child `Board` component is a prop object. If you try `squares.squares` should return an `Array`

```
function Board(squares) {
    // This is the prop object that react passes to a child component.
    console.log(squares);
    console.log(squares.squares)
    console.log(Array.isArray(squares.squares))

    return (
        null
    )

}

export default Board
```

Comment: I see! 'props' is an object containing anything passed to the component and squares is passed to the component. So really I should change the argument in the Board.js component from 'squares' to 'props' to make it more clear. Then I can log props.squares to access the array. This makes much more sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can also use object destructuring on the props object, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77930279/532742) below.

Answer (score 2):

What `Board` component receives is the `props` object, and in your case, one of its properties will be `squares`. So your `Board` code should be:

```
function Board(props) {

    console.log(props.squares)
    console.log(Array.isArray(props.squares))

    return (
        null
    )

}

export default Board
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to offer an alternative solution, which is to use [object destructuring](https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/why-do-we-use-curly-braces-in-react-function-components-parameters/570576/2) to break the props up into their individual names. Wrap the `squares` prop in the function declaration in curly braces:

```
function Board({squares}) {

    console.log(squares)
    console.log(Array.isArray(squares))

    return (
        null
    )

}

export default Board
```

If you were to add another prop to the component, it would look like this:

```
function Board({squares, sayHello}) {

    console.log(squares)
    console.log(Array.isArray(squares))

    return (
        {sayHello ? 'Hello!' : null}
    )

}

export default Board
```

...and your component tag would look like this:

`<Board squares={this.state.gameBoard} sayHello={true} />`

This is kind of a tricky thing to wrap one's head around, but in your original code `squares` is just an alias for `props`, which is why you have to use `squares.squares` to access your named property. It's the same as if you wrote this:

```
function Board(props) {

    console.log(props.squares)
    console.log(Array.isArray(props.squares))

    return (
        null
    )

}

export default Board
```

Ultimately how you do it is just a matter of taste, but it's easy to get tripped up when you're going from classic Javascript function arguments to React component prop objects. Use whichever method is most readable to you/your team.